# How to override OrderController in magento

Tags: magento, controller, magento-1.7

I want to override `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php`. My module is `app/code/local/MW/Adminhtml`.

In my conig.xml I have put the following code.

```
<config>
.....
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>                
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MW_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">MW_Adminhtml</MW_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>                    
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

controller is as follows.

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';
class MW_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    /*
     some code

*/
}
```

But still it loads the core controller class. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: anybody knows how to override `Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php`

Answer (score 2):

This is working example from magento 1.7

In your app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

  <frontend>
  </frontend>

  <adminhtml>
  </adminhtml>

  <admin>
      <routers>
            <adminhtml>     
            <use>admin</use>           
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_ModuleName before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_ModuleName</Namespace_ModuleName>
                    </modules>                    
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
      </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

And controller class:

app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';
class Namespace_ModuleName_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        die('it works');
    }
}
```

Probably using: `<use>admin</use>` is the key in this case.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply nethead. 
I tried all the suggestions on the web including your suggestion. But anything didn't work. So I recreated all the codings and then it worked fine. I'm not sure what was the issue. But now it works fine.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 3 years late but I just spent one hour on this one, so my experience might help some others in the future.

If you are using a magento enterprise edition you have to put:

```
before="Enterprise_SalesArchive_Adminhtml"
```

instead of

```
before="Mage_Adminhtml"
```

in your controller router declaration in the config.xml file, and then the exact code below will work like a charm.